# Minio клиент REST. Как скачать файл?

Tags: http, minio

**Предыстория**:

Есть сервер приложения-хранилище файлов. На нём работают сервисы TUS и Minio. Моя задача - написать клиент на 1С для работы с этой мутью. Файлы загружаются без проблем, ссылки на скачивание получаю вот в таком виде `http://192.168.Х.Х:8000/minio_download/example_body_id/730c57d1726f006016f7be82b21df7a0`
В кластере Minio авторизуюсь, получаю токен, секрет и т.д.

**Вопрос**:

Как построить запрос, чтобы скачать файл?

Пробовал `GET` с реквизитами в заголовках - Access Denied

На `POST` с реквизитами в теле, как `x-www-form-urlencoded` отвечает Unsupported action (добавлял заголовок Action).

А каким должен быть Action для скачивания нагуглить не смог. Подскажите, пожалуйста

**P.S.** Описание любого механизма получения файла от минио также будет полезным. Возможно стоит изменить подход к вопросу именно скачивания

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в Chrome или через Fiddler, какие запросы идут когда вы по ссылке файл пробуете скачивать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, разобрались вместе с коллегой.
Минио требует авторизацию типа AWS Signature (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html). Так, например, выглядит страница авторизации в постмане.

[image: Пример запроса на скачаивание, вкладка "Авторизация]

Запрос должен быть `GET`. Никаких хедеров Action не нужно.

В первую очередь авторизуетесь в Минио.
Запрос `POST`, `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, тело: `Action=AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity&WebIdentityToken=<Ваш JWT-Токен>&Version=2011-06-15`. Токен получаете от вашего OIDC-провайдера (у нас Keyclock).

Минио возвращает вам реквизиты авторизации в виде XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
    <AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult>
        <AssumedRoleUser>
            <Arn></Arn>
            <AssumeRoleId></AssumeRoleId>
        </AssumedRoleUser>
        <Credentials>
            <AccessKeyId>123456GHTREWXvb789</AccessKeyId>
            <SecretAccessKey>lP+123456zxcvbnsdfER+987654QWertTYYUlkjGHJDs</SecretAccessKey>
            <Expiration>2022-07-25T06:32:04Z</Expiration>
            <SessionToken>eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.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.-QExxh-DCosh2SFEQx2rjViXctmlOoebamVdAgE8ra2wRrv47EPmw2vKbSX1k_qyQcqBLu6_W5ylsIyNEhLZ9Q</SessionToken>
        </Credentials>
        <SubjectFromWebIdentityToken>xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx</SubjectFromWebIdentityToken>
    </AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>1704F503B2180C47</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse>
```

Подставляем в хедеры запроса на скачивание AccessKeyId в AccessKey и SecretAccessKey в SecretKey.

Для построения запроса AccessKeyId устанавливается в заголовок `Authorization` после `Credential=`, а на основании SecretKey придется посчитать сигнатуру, как описано в доках амазона по ссылке выше. В заголовок `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` подставляем хеш-256 пустой строки: `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`, потому что в нашем запросе нет тела.

**P.S.:** Собственно весь алгоритм и описан в документации на Amazon Simple Storage Service.

**P.P.S.:** А вот в этом репозитории пример работы с сервисами Амазона из 1С. Спасибо автору *ftomza*
https://gist.github.com/ftomza/2381166bf053b00688b97aa2938a5e44